# Imageview disappeared?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I just made a fresh new project,but when I added an imageview to my layout and launched the emulator,
I can't find it.My goal is,to make the user click the imageview then it directs him to the gallery then he chooses the pic and then it is saved in the database,as simple as that. But when I launch my app I just can't find the imageview.Any ideas on what is going on?

Here is my layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageVieww"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Arabic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/galboy" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Arabic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Arabic"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.268" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Long"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Long"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/English"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.071" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Mob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Mob"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Lat"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.072" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Mob"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.103" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Pass"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.144" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Lat"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Long"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.075" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/English"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="English"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Arabic"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.058" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is where is call my imageview in the code:

```
imageoffarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            askFileReadPermission();
        }
    });
}

private void askFileReadPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_PERM_CODE);
    } else {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERM_CODE || requestCode == READ_PERM_CODE || requestCode == WRITE_PERM_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "الرجاء قبول الكميرة لاجل التصوير", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contentUri = data.getData();
            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(MainActivity.this, contentUri));
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "." + getFileExt(contentUri);
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            databaseHelper.SavingimagepathAR(Uri.fromFile(imageFile).getPath());
            Log.d("tag", "onActivityResult: Gallery Image Uri:  " + Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            imageoffarm.setImageURI(contentUri);


        }

    }
}


private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString());
        return "";
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}

private String getFileExt(Uri contentUri) {
    ContentResolver c = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(c.getType(contentUri));
}
```

Any help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `tools` modifier, It only show image in `Editor mode` and it will show an empty ImageView on screen, but you still can **Click** on it.

after change:

```
<ImageView
    ..
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/galboy" />
```

Comment: Good to know,Honestly that answer is quit more explained,so thanks for the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using are using wrong namespace.

Inside `ImageView`, Use `app:srcCompat` instead of `tools:srcCompat`

Comment: Thank you but,it was auto generated by android studio